# WCF- service method fails to reference entity as parameter

Tags: c#, web-services, wcf, parameters, wsdl

I have the attached WSDL and i need to generate client stubs using Visual Studio 2013, WCF and .NET 4.5. Instead of the expected parameter BoolExpression in the signature, i get an object[] parameter.The generated getResourceList service method looks like this:

```
public TestFieldSOAP.ServiceReference1.ResourceWrapper[] getResourceList(long arg0, long arg1, object[] arg2, object[] arg3)
```

while it should look like this:

```
public TestFieldSOAP.ServiceReference1.ResourceWrapper[] getResourceList(long arg0, long arg1, BoolExpression be, object[] arg3)
```

In a few words, the entity BoolExpression is defined in the schema, but is not referenced as parameter in the method. I have been researching a lot on WSDLs and XSDs, but i haven't found the answer so far.

Any ideas?

**The WSDL**

```
<?xml version="1.0" ?>
<wsdl:definitions xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
    xmlns:wsdl="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/"
    xmlns:tns="http://ResourceManagementBasic.webservices.xxx.com/"
    xmlns:soap12="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/soap12/" xmlns:ns3="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/http"
    xmlns:ns2="http://security.lowLevel.hello.webservices.xxx.com/"
    xmlns:ns1="http://ResourceManagement.hello.xxx.com/" name="WSResourceAdmin_v15Service"
    targetNamespace="http://ResourceManagementBasic.webservices.xxx.com/">
    <wsdl:types>
        <xs:schema xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
            xmlns:tns="http://hello.xxx.com/" elementFormDefault="qualified"
            targetNamespace="http://hello.xxx.com/" version="1.0">
            <xs:complexType name="BoolExpression">
                <xs:sequence>
                    <xs:element maxOccurs="unbounded" name="expressions"
                        nillable="true" type="xs:anyType"></xs:element>
                </xs:sequence>
            </xs:complexType>
            <xs:complexType name="AttributeOperatorValueExpression">
                <xs:complexContent>
                    <xs:extension base="tns:BoolExpression">
                        <xs:sequence>
                            <xs:element name="attribute" nillable="true" type="xs:string"></xs:element>
                            <xs:element name="operator" nillable="true" type="xs:string"></xs:element>
                            <xs:element name="value" nillable="true" type="xs:anyType"></xs:element>
                        </xs:sequence>
                    </xs:extension>
                </xs:complexContent>
            </xs:complexType>
            <xs:complexType name="ANDExpression">
                <xs:complexContent>
                    <xs:extension base="tns:BoolExpression">
                        <xs:sequence></xs:sequence>
                    </xs:extension>
                </xs:complexContent>
            </xs:complexType>
            <xs:complexType name="Wrapper">
                <xs:sequence>
                    <xs:element maxOccurs="unbounded" name="value" nillable="true"
                        type="xs:anyType"></xs:element>
                </xs:sequence>
            </xs:complexType>
        </xs:schema>

        <xs:schema xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
            targetNamespace="http://Wrappers.hello.xxx.com" version="1.0">
            <xs:complexType name="ResourceWrapper">
                <xs:sequence>
                    <xs:element form="qualified" name="Resource" nillable="true" type="xs:long"></xs:element>           
                </xs:sequence>
            </xs:complexType>
        </xs:schema>

        <xs:schema xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
            xmlns:tns="http://ResourceManagementBasic.webservices.xxx.com/"
            xmlns:ns6="http://Wrappers.hello.xxx.com"  xmlns:ns1="http://hello.xxx.com/"
            attributeFormDefault="unqualified" elementFormDefault="unqualified"
            targetNamespace="http://ResourceManagementBasic.webservices.xxx.com/">
            <xs:import namespace="http://hello.xxx.com/"></xs:import>
            <xs:import namespace="http://Wrappers.hello.xxx.com"></xs:import>
            <xs:element name="getResourceList" type="tns:getResourceList"></xs:element>
            <xs:element name="getResourceListResponse" type="tns:getResourceListResponse"></xs:element>
            <xs:complexType name="getResourceListResponse">
                <xs:sequence>
                    <xs:element maxOccurs="unbounded" minOccurs="0" name="return"
                        type="ns6:ResourceWrapper"></xs:element>
                </xs:sequence>
            </xs:complexType>
            <xs:complexType name="getResourceList">
                <xs:sequence>
                    <xs:element minOccurs="0" name="arg0" type="xs:long"></xs:element>
                    <xs:element minOccurs="0" name="arg1" type="xs:long"></xs:element>
                    <xs:element minOccurs="0" name="arg2" type="ns1:BoolExpression" form="qualified"></xs:element>
                    <xs:element maxOccurs="unbounded" minOccurs="0" name="arg3" type="xs:anyType"></xs:element>
                </xs:sequence>
            </xs:complexType>   
        </xs:schema>
    </wsdl:types>


    <wsdl:message name="getResourceListResponse">
        <wsdl:part element="tns:getResourceListResponse" name="parameters">
        </wsdl:part>
    </wsdl:message>
    <wsdl:message name="getResourceList">
        <wsdl:part element="tns:getResourceList" name="parameters">
        </wsdl:part>
    </wsdl:message>

    <wsdl:portType name="WSResourceAdmin_v15">
        <wsdl:operation name="getResourceList">
            <wsdl:input message="tns:getResourceList" name="getResourceList">
            </wsdl:input>
            <wsdl:output message="tns:getResourceListResponse" name="getResourceListResponse">
            </wsdl:output>
        </wsdl:operation>
    </wsdl:portType>    


    <wsdl:binding name="WSResourceAdmin_v15ServiceSoapBinding"
        type="tns:WSResourceAdmin_v15">
        <soap12:binding style="document"
            transport="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/http"></soap12:binding>
        <wsdl:operation name="getResourceList">
            <soap12:operation soapAction="" style="document"></soap12:operation>
            <wsdl:input name="getResourceList">
                <soap12:body use="literal"></soap12:body>
            </wsdl:input>
            <wsdl:output name="getResourceListResponse">
                <soap12:body use="literal"></soap12:body>
            </wsdl:output>
        </wsdl:operation>
    </wsdl:binding>


    <wsdl:service name="WSResourceAdmin_v15Service">
        <wsdl:port binding="tns:WSResourceAdmin_v15ServiceSoapBinding"
            name="WSResourceAdmin_v15Port">
            <soap12:address
                location="xxx"></soap12:address>
        </wsdl:port>
    </wsdl:service>
</wsdl:definitions>
```

Here is also the method signature of the generated getResource method stub

```
[System.Xml.Serialization.XmlArrayItemAttribute("expressions", Namespace="http://hello.xxx.com/")]
        public object[] arg2 {
```

---

**EDIT 8th of Feb 2016** 
It seems like valid fixed is right: the object[] is a result of the anyType sequence defined within the BoolExpression type. I read that removing the import to the namespace of the BoolExpression will cause the svcutil generator to include the BoolExpression as a parameter in the generated method. Would this work? Or would you propose to use another workaround? I cannot test my assumption at the time since i am running from one .NET bug to the other

Answer (score 0):

Its how wsdl defines it.
Elements that are type="**:anyType" are mapped to Object objects.

Comment: Thanks for your response; i understand what you 're saying. I would however expect to have a BoolExpression as a parameter in the generated method and not the enclosed "field members" of it. After all, the getResourceList request references BoolExpression and not a sequence of anyType. (I added a code of the generated class above in the original post)

Comment: BoolExpression acts as base class for AttributeOperatorValueExpression and ANDExpression allowing both to have a sequence of anyType named "elements".
But unlike AttributeOperatorValueExpression that extends it properly by adding new elements, ANDExpression sequence is empty! It adds no new elements what  ANDExpression and BoolExpression redundant.

Funny remark: if in getResourceList you replace "ns1:BoolExpression" with "ns1:ANDExpression", you will have ANDExpression referenced as parameter in the method! :)